# Bringing computer parts into Iran

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airport-security, electronic-items, iran

I'm going on holiday to Iran and an Iranian friend has asked me to bring a few computer parts with me from Australia, the total value is about $700.

I'll be taking a motherboard, AMD CPU and memory.

Will it be a problem when passing customs in Iran?

Comment: If the goods are new, according to this https://www.otc-global.com/en/middle-east/iran/moving-to-iran/customs-regulations-in-iran/ import duty would be payable

Comment: I'm not sure you can legally do it, because of US export rules (which apply also outside US). I would check with your government site (and the shop) if you are allowed to transport such items to Iran.

Comment: Much as the Americans would like to think so, their rules don't apply outside the US. The products in question were probably made in the Far East or Asia and were never in the US anyway. Australian export rules may apply, though.

Comment: Back in the 90's I considered exporting PC's to Ukraine from the UK. I called up the Foreign Office, I think it was, and asked for advice about the legalities with which they were very helpful. (I can't actually remember what they said but they included some practicalities which ended up killing the idea. Veri different now, though.) Call you government. They might actually help!

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you won't have a problem, however it depends on which airport/border crossing you're entering the country from and how strict the individual officer dealing with you is. Most airports are fairly laid back and will be hassle-free. I would suggest you either attach the CPU and the memory onto the motherboard so that it looks as one unit, or maybe distribute them in different areas when packing, whichever that you think would attract the least attention (either to human eyes or to Xray machines!). If they do spot it, you just tell them that it's a present for your friend. worst-case scenario, they will charge you the import duty, but again, it is all hit and miss and you may not get into any problem at all. Also consider 1% possibility of things going differently than what I explained.

Tip: The nicer, cooler and more polite that you look, the less you'll run into problems with officials in general.

Resource: I'm from there and have traveled a handful number of times in and out.